# Is it possible to implement a method in one interface by others method in this interface?

Tags: go, interface

For example, an interface named Computable, which has two methods: `Sqrt()` and `Abs()`.

If I want to add a method named `Curve()` to compute the sum of sqrt and abs.

```golang
type Computable interace { 
    Sqrt() number  // method 1
    Abs() number   // method 2
    Curve() number // method should call Sqrt() + Abs()
}
```

Obvoiously, no need to rewrite the third method for all interface implementation. In C++/Java, it is very easy to resovle it.But who can tell how to implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no default method implementations in Go.

The easiest solution in your case would be to move `Curve()` outside of the interface, and implement it as a simple function:

```
type Computable interface {
    Sqrt() number // method 1
    Abs() number  // method 2
}

func Curve(c Computable) number {
    return c.Sqrt() + c.Abs()
}
```

If it must be part of the interface, then you may create a single implementation of `Curve()` that uses a value of `Computable` as its "source":

```
type curveImpl struct {
    Computable
}

func (c curveImpl) Curve() number {
    return c.Sqrt() + c.Abs()
}
```

Concrete types that wish to implement `Computable` may embed `curveImpl`, but for it to work, it must be initialized properly:

```
type Foo struct {
    curveImpl
}

func (Foo) Sqrt() number { return 2.0 }
func (Foo) Abs() number  { return 4.0 }

func main() {
    f := Foo{}
    f.curveImpl = curveImpl{f}

    fmt.Println(f.Curve())
}
```

The above example outputs `6` (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/IGhTKvEHeLg)).

As you can see there is some hassle involved making this work. So in this case it's questionable whether it's worth it. If `Curve()` is this simple, I would just rather implement it where needed. If `Curve()` would be a lot more complex, then maybe the trade-off is worth it.

Again: easiest would be to use a `Curve()` *function* instead of a *method* here.

Comment: Thanks, it can work. But, it looks a bit complicated to user to intialize the structure and its curlImpl field. Especially when I have many curve likes methods to implement. Maybe it is caused by go's limitation.

Comment: Even sometimes I have no chance to initialize them, for example, for Unmarshaler caller. Why does not go provide generics...

Comment: In this case you really just should go with the function implementation (instead of method).

Comment: Curve may have hundreds of lines. Dozens of different structures should implement Curve. I hate similiar codes...

Comment: If it's not needed to be part of the interface, there is no repetition in a single utility function.